# similar articles suggestion based on article read by a user

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, recommendation-engine

I am looking for the best algorithm to use for article suggestion in my projects. We have bunch of 1000 articles. I would like to recommend similar articles to users based on the article he is reading. Which algorithm best suits this. I tried content based recommendation, which involves training the model. In my case it can be simple text based similarity to the article the user is reading and not the history of articles read by users

Comment: This question is more suited for https://stats.stackexchange.com/ .

Answer (score -1):

maybe look at what karpathy has done with arxiv sanity.

https://github.com/karpathy/arxiv-sanity-preserver